# Spring Data JPA - simulate a "create + join" query for an existing collection

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Let's say I have a List of entities:

```
List<SomeEntity> myEntities = new ArrayList<>();
```

SomeEntity.java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "entity_table")
public class SomeEntity{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;
private int score;

public SomeEntity() {}

public SomeEntity(long id, int score) {
    this.id = id;
    this.score = score;
}
```

MyEntityRepository.java:

```
@Repository
public interface MyEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<SomeEntity, Long> {

List<SomeEntity> findAllByScoreGreaterThan(int Score);
}
```

So when I run:

```
myEntityRepository.findAllByScoreGreaterThan(10);
```

Then Hibernate will load all of the records in the table into memory for me.
There are millions of records, so I don't want that. Then, in order to intersect, I need to compare each record in the result set to my List.
In native MySQL, what I would have done in this situation is:

1. create a temporary table and insert into it the entities' ids from the List.
2. join this temporary table with the "entity_table", use the score filter and then only pull the entities that are relevant to me (the ones that were in the list in the first place).

This way I gain a big performance increase, avoid any OutOfMemoryErrors and have the machine of the database do most of the work.

Is there a way to achieve such an outcome with Spring Data JPA's query methods (with hibernate as the JPA provider)? I couldn't find in the documentation or in SO any such use case.

Comment: you should declare Page<SomeEntity> findAllByScoreGreaterThan(int Score, Pageable pageable); in your repository to use benefit of pagination

Comment: But this is again a performance issue, only from a program speed point of view. If I have 1 million records, then I will have to load all of them, but in pages. In the MySQL way, I don't even go there - the query filters out everything for me when joining.

Answer (score 3):

I understand you have a set of `entity_table` identifiers and you want to find each `entity_table` whose identifier is in that subset *and* whose score is greater than a given score.

So the obvious question is: how did you arrive to the initial subset of `entity_table`s and couldn't you just add the criteria of that query to your query that also checks for "score is greater than *x*"?

But if we ignore that, I think there's two possible solutions. If the list of `some_entity` identifiers is small (what exactly is "small" depends on your database), you could just use an `IN` clause and define your method as:

```
List<SomeEntity> findByScoreGreaterThanAndIdIn(int score, Set<Long) ids)
```

If the number of identifiers is too large to fit in an `IN` clause (or you're worried about the performance of using an `IN` clause) and you need to use a temporary table, the recipe would be:

1. Create an entity that maps to your temporary table. Create a Spring Data JPA repository for it:

   ```
   class TempEntity {
       @Id
       private Long entityId;
   }

   interface TempEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<TempEntity,Long> { }
   ```
2. Use its `save` method to save all the entity identifiers into the temporary table. As long as you enable insert batching this should perform all right -- how to enable differs per database and JPA provider, but for Hibernate at the very least set the `hibernate.jdbc.batch_size` Hibernate property to a sufficiently large value. Also `flush()` and `clear()` your `entityManager` regularly or all your temp table entities will accumulate in the persistence context and you'll still run out of memory. Something along the lines of:

   ```
   int count = 0;
   for (SomeEntity someEntity : myEntities) {
       tempEntityRepository.save(new TempEntity(someEntity.getId());
       if (++count == 1000) {
           entityManager.flush();
           entityManager.clear();
       }
   }
   ```
3. Add a `find` method to your `SomeEntityRepository` that runs a native query that does the select on `entity_table` and joins to the temp table:

   ```
   @Query("SELECT id, score FROM entity_table t INNER JOIN temp_table tt ON t.id = tt.id WHERE t.score > ?1", nativeQuery = true)
   List<SomeEntity> findByScoreGreaterThan(int score);
   ```
4. Make sure you run both methods in the same transaction, so create a method in a `@Service` class that you annotate with `@Transactional(Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)` that calls both repository methods in succession. Otherwise your temp table's contents will be gone by the time the `SELECT` query runs and you'll get zero results.

You might be able to avoid native queries by having your temp table entity have a `@ManyToOne` to `SomeEntity` since then you can join in JPQL; I'm just not sure if you'll be able to avoid actually loading the `SomeEntity`s to insert them in that case (or if creating a new `SomeEntity` with just an ID would work). But since you say you already have a list of `SomeEntity` that's perhaps not a problem.

I need something similar myself, so will amend my answer as I get a working version of this.

Comment: Well done! This answer was the best way for my case.  Since MySQL 5.6 does not support array as an input in a stored procedure, Another option would be to pass a cvs in one parameter.  FIND_IN_SET() to prevent sql injection.   1 downside to this is performance may not be as good as using a JOIN on the temp table.  Another downside of a csv param is max length of varchar. (21,844 chars for utf8)     However if those 2 things are not important and your only comparing 1 column, cvs *might* work

Comment: @Frans, I'm not confident with the approach as the temp table wouldn't be consistent when multiple users access it with different score

Comment: @SivaramKumar Gosh, this was a while ago, but generally speaking, you’ll populate and use the temp table in the same transaction and then (I think) the DBMS should take care of throwing it away at the end of the transaction. Transaction isolation means that (just like for any other table) you won’t see what’s happening in another transaction that wasn’t committed before yours started. But you should definitely test these type of scenarios to be sure the reality matches the theory!

Answer (score 1):

You can:

1) Make a paginated native query via JPA (remember to add an order clause to it) and process a fixed amount of records

2) Use a StatelessSession (see [the documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/devguide/en-US/html/ch04.html))

Comment: This answer has educated me, but it's not addressing the issue. See my comment to my question. I want the database to do the work and get me the records I need, not to load everything in batches.